# Is this bipartite graph optimization task NP-complete?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, np-complete, bipartite

I have been trying to find out a polynomial-time algorithm to solve this problem, but in vain. I'm not familiar with the NP-complete thing. Just wondering whether this problem is actually NP-complete, and I should not waste any further effort trying to come up with a polynomial-time algorithm.

The problem is easy to describe and understand. Given a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), what is the minimum number of vertices you have to select from one vertex set, say A, so that each vertex in B is adjacent to at least one selected vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is NP-hard; there's an easy reduction from [Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) (in fact it's arguably just a different way of expressing the same problem).  In Set Cover we're given a ground set F, a collection C of subsets of F, and a number k, and we want to know if we can cover all n ground set elements of F by choosing at most k of the sets in C.  To reduce this to your problem: Make a vertex in B for each ground element, and a vertex in A for each set in C, and add an edge uv whenever ground element v is in set u.  If there was some algorithm to efficiently solve the problem you describe, it could solve the instance I just described, which would immediately give a solution to the original Set Cover problem (which is known to be NP-hard).

Interestingly, if we are allowed to choose vertices *from the entire graph* (rather than just from A), the problem is solvable in polynomial time using bipartite maximum matching algorithms, due to [Kőnig's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig's_theorem_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: Nice reduction. Hopefully, I will inscribe the Set Cover problem in my memory this time.

Comment: Glad I could help :)  I actually ran up against this exact problem only a couple of weeks ago, so it was fresh in my mind.